# Full path figure export to LaTeX error in org-mode in Windows 7

Tags: org-mode, org-export, emacs24.4

when I export a full path figure , like: 
`[[file:c:/Users/admin/Desktop/1.png]]`

to LaTeX in org-mode, a result of
`{//c:/Users/admin/Desktop/1.png}`

was generated. One more `//` was generated in front of `c:`, 
which is an error in LaTeX.

How can I solve this problem?

I have posted this problem to org-mode mail list, but nobody replied me, so I continued to ask here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: In cygwin environment one could use `/cygdrive/c` instead of `c:`.

Comment: Thanks, but my windows hasn't cygwin installed. Sorry, I realized it is a windows relevant problem. @Tobias

Comment: I just tried `[[file:c:/temp/1.png]]` and got `\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{c:/temp/1.png}
% Emacs 24.4.1 (Org mode 8.2.7c)`.

Comment: @Tobias It is weird. I tried again and again just now, but still same problem. Is there any other special config for your org-mode? or you use Cygwin?

Comment: Just tried with `emacs -Q` (emacs without customization) under Cygwin. Delivers `\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{c:/temp/1.png}
% Emacs 24.4.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)`. As you see: other org-mode version but same result.

Comment: @Tobias, we are using same org-mode and emacs version. But why mine can not produce proper result. How do you set up your figure attr_latex headers?

Comment: As I told you: No customization at all.

Comment: @Tobias, okay... Thanks anyway. Something strange in my org-mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in org-mode 8.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

This bug exists in version 9.x.x when exporting to html

And I fixed the bug by changing this function and compiling ox.el

```
(defun org-export-file-uri (filename)
  "Return file URI associated to FILENAME."
  (cond ((string-prefix-p "//" filename) (concat "file:" filename))
    ((not (file-name-absolute-p filename)) filename)
    ((org-file-remote-p filename) (concat "file:/" filename))
    (t
     (let ((fullname (expand-file-name filename)))
       (concat (if (string-prefix-p "/" fullname) "file://" "file:///")
           fullname)))))
```

> Just replace "file:///" into "file://".